# possessive articles in a puzzle

Tags: possessive-pronoun, possessive

I have a puzzle about `possessive article` here that made me a little confused. There are three dogs Bello, Max and Rex, according to these sentences, Bello is masculine and Max is Feminine, but what about gender of the whelp Rex? And whom does the last `Seiner` refer to?

> Bello ist der Hund ihres Mannes.
>
> Rex ist der Hund seines Kindes.
>
> Max ist der Hund ihrer Mutter.
>
> Rex ist der Hund seiner Kinder.

Comment: Who do the possessive articles refer to?

Comment: 1. You don't have possessive *articles*, but possessive *pronouns*. And they refere to somebody outside the sentence. For example sentence 2 in Englisch: »Bello is the dog *of his* child« can be correct, but also »Bello is the dog *of her* child«. The person (either father or mother of the child) is not mentioned in the sentence. The gender of the dog doesn't influence the gender of the pronoun, because the pronoun doesn't refer to the dog, but to a person outside the sentence.

Comment: Sorry, I was actually asking, I had not seen your last sentence. I do not understand whose husband, child, mother we are talking about.

Comment: Dear @HubertSchölnast! thanks, But here in the book "Studio d B1" it has written as "Possesivartikel" and I couldn't find "possesive articles" in tag lists either.

Comment: Oh! Now I understand! thanks to you @HubertSchölnast! you're right, the person is not mentioned in sentence and is outside of the sentence! So, gender of pronouns don't get influenced by gender of dogs! that was the reason that made me confused!

Comment: Bezüglich Possessivartikel: "In der modernen Linguistik wird Possessivpronomen auch in einem engeren Sinne verwendet und bezeichnet dann nur Wörter wie seines (in: das ist seines), aber nicht Wörter wie sein (in: sein Haus). Letztere werden dann Possessivartikel (auch: Possessivbegleiter, Possessivdeterminanten, Possessivdeterminative) genannt." https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessiv

Comment: Danke @Iris für die Referenz.

Comment: @Hubert: Surely sentence 2 can only mean "Rex (not Bello!) is the dog of _his_ child"? So the unmentioned person must be the father, not the mother.

Comment: @TonyK: Yes. But »Rex ist der Hund **ihres** Kindes.« would also be a correct German sentence, even if Rex was a male dog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are three dogs Bello, Max and Rex, according to these sentences, Bello is masculine and Max is Feminine, but what about gender of the whelp Rex?

Yes, there are three dogs. However, only the names of the dogs and the use of the masculine form of 'Hund' imply their gender - *not* the possessive pronouns. Furthermore, it is not evident from the text that Rex is a whelp.

I'll explain the separate sentences in detail below:

---

> Bello ist der Hund ihres Mannes.

Bello is a dog, belonging to a man that is the husband of a *woman* that is referenced

> Rex ist der Hund seines Kindes.

Rex is also a dog, belonging to the child of a *man* that is referenced

> Max ist der Hund ihrer Mutter.

Max is a dog, belonging to the mother of a *woman* being referenced

> Rex ist der Hund seiner Kinder.

Rex is a dog, which belongs to the kids of a *man* being referenced